# apk big size with ionic 4 build

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

Before I got the output, it was 9 megabytes.
but now it is 17.8MB.
I opened apk in android studio with Analyze apk.
assets folder is very big and there are several numbers from each file.
[image]

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 7.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.1, (and 16 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/omid/programming_tools/android-sdk)
NodeJS            : v10.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 6.8.0
OS                : Linux 4.20
```

I use of this command :

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

What has happened ?

Comment: resolved problem.removing www folder from project and build.

Answer (score 2):

This is a massive flaw in ionic 4. I recommend following these build instructions:

Test APK:

Delete 'www' folder from project

```
ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs
```

Production APK:

Delete 'www' folder from project

```
ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs --release --prod
```

In theory `--minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs` are all applied by `--prod` but you never know with Ionic