# Ionic 4 build production huge apk generated

Tags: android, cordova, apk, ionic4

I'm trying to build my ionic 4 app, but generates a huge apk with almost 50 mb,

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206777/apk-big-size-with-ionic-4-build) (remove www folder) and didnt work,

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988174/ionic-android-apk-file-size-way-too-big-how-to-decrease-the-size-of-app-for-an) and nothing

After analyzing the apk i found out that the lib folder uses more than 80% of the size of the app, how do i fix this?
[image]

The previous version (i'm migrating from ionic 3 by creating a new one and reinstalling everything) with the --prod flag was around 8~9 mb and now on ionic 4, 50 mb?
The plugin list is

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.2.4 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-calendar 5.1.5 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-chooser 1.2.5 "Chooser"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-document-scanner 4.2.1 "Scan"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 6.2.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio 3.0.0 "FingerprintAllInOne"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 8.2.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-headercolor 1.0 "HeaderColor"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-stripe 1.5.3 "cordova-plugin-stripe"
cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker 2.3.3 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.2 "SocialSharing"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.1 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.7.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.4 "Launch Navigator"
```

and this is the ionic info output

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.9 (C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.2.9)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Hey, can you share more details of your project? which native plugins are you using? how much your assets weight etc?

Comment: Yes, Sergey is right, it depends on native plugins... If you use for example `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` then of course you'll have a big size of apk, so until we have the details we can't really help

Comment: description edited with the info guys, thanks

Comment: How do i remove the cordova plugin webview then? can i remove it?